# Retrieving input argument at index via alias in zsh

Tags: function, shell, scripting, zsh

I am trying to create functions and aliases in ZSH that make parameters handling easier to read.

As such, I wanted to create things like the example below:

```
#!/bin/zsh
myCustomFunction(){
  local numberOfParameters=$(count-parameters)
  local lastParameter=$(get-parameter $numberOfParameters)
  echo "Number of parameters: $numberOfParameters"
  echo "Last parameter is: $lastParameter"
}
```

Where `count-parameters` is defined below:

```
#!/bin/zsh
alias count-parameters='echo "$#"
```

How would I be able to implement `get-parameter`? I have been trying with `"$@"`, as suggested in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621124/how-to-pass-all-arguments-of-a-function-along-to-another-command), but that does not seem to work.

My desired result is that given an input such as:

```
myCustomFunction.sh "First param" "Second param" "Third param"
```

The output would be:

```
Number of parameters: 3
Last parameter: Third param
```

Comment: Why would you want to use an alias?

Comment: (indeed, the "alias" factoid in the bash IRC channel for a very long time said only "if you have to ask, use a function instead").

Comment: BTW, your title says bash, your tags say zsh. Pick only one.

Comment: (zsh is deliberately quite incompatible, making design decisions that break the POSIX sh standard everywhere its authors think that standard codifies bad ideas, while bash is almost a strict superset).

Comment: (and annoyingly, zsh doesn't let you do `num=3; echo "${!num}"` to get the contents of `$3`, whereas that _is_ supported in bash)

Comment: *"indexed starting at 1?!"* ....... That's not a bug, that's a feature! (-; Cheers to all!

Comment: And ... LinkM ... : Why an alias? You're already comfortable with functions, why not a function instead of an alias? Good luck.

Comment: I don't have a preference concerning aliases vs functions. I just need something that achieves the desired result in ZSH.

Comment: BTW, if zsh has any equivalent to `BASH_ARGV` that provides another easy implementation route.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `${(P)num}` is the zsh equivalent to bash `${!num}` fwiw

Comment: And `setopt ksh_arrays` to get 0 indexed arrays, but doing that globally will break lots of things.

Comment: The last parameter of a zsh function or script can be fetched using `$@[-1]`. The number of parameters are accessible using `$#`. I don't see how this is related to an _alias_.

Comment: @user1934428, the presumptive reason for OP's use of aliases is so they don't need to explicitly pass `"$@"` through to a child function invocation arguments. I personally think that's a little silly -- it's sacrificing performance for that tiny bit of clarity -- but it's not quite _entirely_ without benefit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Through trial and error, I was able to accomplish the desired result.

Here's how I did it.

1. Count parameters alias

```
#!/bin/zsh
alias count-parameters='echo "$#"'
```

For get-parameter, I had to perform multiple operations (hacky way but it works)

- Save each parameter in a file (each parameter separated by the NUL character)
- Store the text within the file in a variable and loop over each character. Use the NUL character to determine where one parameter finishes and the next begins. Then, remove the file that was temporarily created

```
#!/bin/zsh
export tempParameterFile="$HOME/.params.txt"
alias save-parameters='save_parameters "$@"'
```

```
#!/bin/zsh
save_parameters(){
  numberOfParams=${#}
  if [ "$numberOfParams" -gt 0 ]; then
    rm -f "$tempParameterFile"
    while (( $# ))
    do
      echo -n "$1" >> "$tempParameterFile"
      echo -ne $'\0' >> "$tempParameterFile" # Adding NUL character after each parameter
      shift
    done
  fi
}
```

```
#!/bin/zsh

get_parameter(){
  local indexToUse=$1
  #echo "Called get_parameter for index $1"
  local currentIndex=0
  local nullCharacter=$'\0'
  local currentParam=""
  local allParameters=$(cat "$tempParameterFile")
  local currentCharacter=""
  for (( index=0; index<${#allParameters}; index++ ));
  do
    currentCharacter="${allParameters:$index:1}"
    if [ "$currentCharacter" = "$nullCharacter" ]; then # When the null character is found
      if [ "$currentIndex" = "$indexToUse" ];then # If the current index matches the desired index
        echo "$currentParam" # We found the word we were looking for
        return 0
      else # If the current index is lower than the desired index
        currentIndex=$(( $currentIndex + 1 )) # We increase the current index
        currentParam="" # And reset the current parameter
      fi
    else # If the character read is not  the null character
      currentParam="$currentParam$currentCharacter" # We append the character to the current param
    fi
  done
}
```

```
#!/bin/zsh
alias get-parameter='save_parameters "$@" && get_parameter'
```

When running the command:

```
╰─$ myCustomFunction.sh "One param" "Second param" "Third param" "Fourth param"
Number of parameters: 4
Last parameter: Fourth param
```

The desired result is achieved.

EDIT: Updated code to address the possibility of an input parameter having a new line in it. Now using, as suggested in the comments, the NUL character to differentiate between parameters.

Comment: Assuming one line per parameter isn't sound: command-line arguments can contain literal newlines. What if someone passes `yourprogram $'two\nlines'`?

Comment: (the only character that can't exist in a command-line argument, and thus the only character that's safe to use to _separate_ entries in a list of command line arguments, is the NUL).

Comment: Yeah, the solution is not perfect, that is why even I defined it hacky.

Comment: @rowboat not across an execv boundary; that's an OS limitation, the shell has no choice in it.

Comment: ...to be honest, the primary reason I'm a little unclear how to react here is the lack of any comment on why the answer I added doesn't meet your needs, in conjunction with the addition of one understood to have limitations on when it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: I have updated the code to use the NUL character instead of the new line. I did not see your code, Charlie, until after I posted my own solution. When I tried your code, it wasn't working, so I just decided to update my version to account for the possibility of new lines being present in input parameters and introduced the NUL character as you suggested. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Understood! If you do ever happen to have the time to explain how the answer I wrote didn't work, or write a test case, I'd appreciate it. (In the interim, I'll put together a https://repl.it/ link that someone can follow to see it functioning as-intended) -- https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/PromotedImpressiveNormalform#run-all

Answer (score 2):

You can make this work by having your aliases be thin wrappers around functions that do the actual work.

The below has a shebang for zsh, but is written to be functional with bash as well.

```
#!/bin/zsh

# define functions to be called by the aliases below
_count-parameters() { echo "$#"; }
_get-parameter() {
  local last_idx tgt
  # make args array 1-indexed whether running in bash or zsh
  local -a args=( ${BASH_VERSION:+ "_" } "$@" )
  tgt=$(( "${args[$#]}" ))
  echo "${args[$tgt]}"
}

# this is supposed to be run with zsh, so the below line _should_ be moot
# for bash, aliases are off by default in scripts; turn them on explicitly
[[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && shopt -s expand_aliases

alias count-parameters='_count-parameters "$@"'
alias get-parameter='_get-parameter "$@"'

myCustomFunction() {
  local numberOfParameters lastParameter
  numberOfParameters=$(count-parameters)
  lastParameter=$(get-parameter "$numberOfParameters")
  echo "Number of parameters: $numberOfParameters"
  echo "Last parameter is: $lastParameter"
}

myCustomFunction "First param" "Second param" "Third param"
```

Comment: What's the point in testing BASH_VERSION in a zsh script? Actually, the code would not work with bash anyway, because of `${args[$#]}`. Array indexing starts in bash with 0, not like in zsh with 1.

Comment: @user1934428, see how we inject `"_"` in the array if-and-only-if the shell is bash? That way you get 1-indexing with either shell. You might actually _test_ this code on both shells -- as I did -- before making claims as to its portability. For that matter, there's even a comment in the code saying as much.

Comment: One can see this working against both bash and zsh at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/PromotedImpressiveNormalform#run-all

Comment: Ah, now I get the idea! You prepend the array with a dummy first element. I see the point, even though I don't like the design. I must admit that I don't see much benefit in writing code which is supposed to run in both shells, and the OP did not ask for it either. But **if** such a situation arises, your approach is certainly promising.

Comment: @user1934428, a previous version of the question specified bash in the title. Granted, that ambiguity is long since solved.